# Not receiving answer email notifications

Tags: support

I'm not receiving any emails notifying me of answers to my questions even though I've selected the option to receive them daily. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it seems ["daily" is interpreted as "after two days, unless we're slower"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23442/slow-email-notification). The creators of this site [want you to visit it often](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600), so they made an e-mail system that you can't rely on for quick answers.

This site is part of [a larger network of Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/), and many answers about the workings of this site can be found on [the general meta site of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user).

Comment: *Jan Fabry:* I find it ironic that they don't send emails to get people to visit it often. Clearly they've never heard of the *"out of site, out of mind"* principle.  Yes you and I come here often, but most people will forget about the site more often than they think about it.

Comment: @Mike: I know [Joel has a clear idea about this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/BuildingCommunitieswithSo.html): *"If you offer the "notify me" checkbox, these people will post their question, check the box, and never come back. [...]  If you eliminate the checkbox, people are left with no choice but to check back every once in a while. And while they're checking back, they might read another post which looks interesting."* But this might not apply to "hit-and-run" low quality questions, and maybe we get more of those?

Comment: *@Jan* Frankly, I think Joel is just wrong on that part. He's right on a lot, but that doesn't make his opinions infallible. His approach is no good for the person who is not already invested in the site, although many of those would be invested if they were notified more often. BTW, at one point when I was actively riding my Aprilia I spent tons of time on the Aprilia Forum in large part because it constantly notified me of updates. FWIW.